# Common.lang 3 does not exist on import

Tags: java, apache-commons

I have a lib folder in my project folder called commons-lang3-3.5 because apparantly I needed to download that. I import like this

```
import org.apache.commons.lang3.*;
```

and I attempt to capitalize the first letter of each word with

```
WordUtils.capitalize(city);
```

and then I get the error

```
weatherproject.java:2: error: package org.apache.commons.lang3 does not  exist
import org.apache.commons.lang3.*;
^

weatherproject.java:17: error: cannot find symbol
            WordUtils.capitalize(city);
            ^
symbol:   variable WordUtils
location: class weatherproject
```

Comment: How are you building? What tools are you using? Because you need to add that jar to your build path.

Comment: I'm only using sublime text editor and going javac /path, and I added the jar to the same folder my project was in and that didn't do anything

Comment: Correct, because you specify the classpath with the `-cp` argument to `javac`. Adding the jar file to the folder does (as you note) nothing.

Comment: Now i'm getting this after I switched the way I imported and adding class path Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/lang3/text/WordUtils

Comment: No how are you running it? Because you also need to add that jar to your classpath when you execute it.

Comment: with javac -cp commons-lang3-3.5.jar weatherproject.java I couldn't find anything on downloading a WordUtils jar though

Comment: It also compiles fine but executing is when the error comes up

Comment: `java -cp .:commons-lang3-3.5.jar weatherproject`

Comment: Now I get this error when trying to compile weatherproject.java:3: error: package org.apache.commons.lang3 does not exist when I try to import with import org.apache.commons.lang3.*;